# Radio button not staying checked when clicking another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this parent component

**Question**

```
<template>
  <div class="question-container">
    <div class="question">
      <h2>{{ number }}. {{ question.question }}</h2>
      <Choice :choices="question.choices"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Choice from "./Choice.vue";

export default {
  name: "Question",
  props: {
    question: String,
    number: Number,
  },
  components: {
    Choice,
  },
};
</script>
```

and this child component named

**Choice**

```
<template>
  <div class="choice">
    <div v-for="(choice, index) in choices" v-bind:key="index">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" />
        <span class="label-text">{{ choice }}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Choice",
  props: {
    choices: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

The issue is that when you select a radio button on one component, then when you go to another component and try to select a radio button on the component. The radio button gets unselected from the other component. Multiple **Question** components are rendered and each of them has radio buttons. When you click a radio button on a **Question** component, all selected radio button gets unselected from the other components. Hope I made sense. How would I fix this?

Comment: Each radio will need a unique name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `name=` attribute on a radio button is what HTML uses to group it with other radios for the same input. You'll need this to be unique per question.

The questions already have a `number` prop (which I hope is some sort of ID? If not, you could add an id attribute to each)

I would pass this to the choices:

```
<Choice :choices="question.choices" :id="number"/>
```

Then render it in the Choice:

```
<template>
  <div class="choice">
    <div v-for="(choice, index) in choices" v-bind:key="index">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" :name="`answer-${id}`" />
        <span class="label-text">{{ choice }}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Choice",
  props: {
    choices: Array,
    id: Number
  },
};
</script>
```

This renders

```
<input type="radio" name="answer-1" />
```